# Bottom border appears when I open a page on a smaller screen

Tags: css

I have a page containing several sections.

One of the section has a list on it, when I'm opening it on a bigger screen it looks OK, but when I open it on a smaller screen, it will be scrollable (which is OK) but it also has a thick border on bottom, the list is not visible down to the end of the screen.

There is no other sections under it.

This is the CSS of the list section:

```
.sites-list {
    height: 50%;
    padding-left: 10rem;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #a9611a;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Any ideas how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: You can use `border-bottom:0px !important;`

Comment: @RohitVerma tried it, unfortunately is not working

Comment: Can you show the output ? How it looks like?

Comment: in your given image , I can't find any border-bottom.

Comment: you can see in the first picture that there the list is not shown to the end of the screen, it is a white border which doesn't let them been shown. hope it is clear

Comment: Can you provide full section code? and why you have given `bottom:0` as there is no any positioned section.?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/AAU4SQux this is the whole CSS file. the section I talk about is `.sites-list`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
border-bottom:0px;
```

or use @media query with screen size and in that use this border-bottom.